# Two different definitions of Big-O (relating to the absolute value)

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, asymptotics

On [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation#Family_of_Bachmann.E2.80.93Landau_notations) we have $f \in O(g)$ if there exists $C > 0$ such that
$$
 |f(x)| \le C g(x)
$$
for $x$ large enough, on the other side for example [here](http://web.mit.edu/16.070/www/lecture/big_o.pdf) it is defined as
$$
 |f(x)| \le C |g(x)|
$$
for large enough $x$.

> But what definition is "the right one"?

Does this make any difference?

Comment: Keep in mind that different subfields have different conventions for what some of the asymptotic notations mean.

Answer (score 1):

The two definitions lead to equivalent concepts.  In the first definition, since $|f(x)| \geq 0$, one cannot have $g(x) < 0$ at any $x$ anyway, so might as well replace $g(x)$ by $|g(x)$.

Comment: But what if the 2nd definition holds, does this imply the first? (btw guess you mean the 1st definition in your answer, not the 2nd...)

Comment: Yes, you are right, I meant "1st" and have corrected the comment.  And, yes, the 2nd definition implies the first, because if $g(x) \geq 0$, then
$$
|(g(x)| = g(x),
$$
and if $g(x) < 0$, then the inequality in the first definition cannot hold in principle.

Comment: I see that the 1st implies the 2nd as the 1st forces $g(x) \ge 0$, but I do not see the other direction as you say: as the 2nd might hold, but the 1st might fails if $g(x) < 0$ is large enough for the 2nd equation to hold??

Comment: " if g(x)<0 is large enough for the 2nd equation to hold"

How can that be?:)  We know that $C > 0$, and so if $g(x) < 0$, then the right-hand side of the inequality is negative: $Cg(x) < 0$.  Meanwhile, the left-hand side is nonnegative: $|f(x)| \geq 0$.

Comment: In the 2nd equation there are also $|\cdot |$-signs around the $g(x)$, so when $g(x) < 0$ then $C\cdot |g(x)| > 0$, so the 2nd one can hold very well, or not???

Comment: Sorry, I got them mixed up again.  I recommend that you pick a function $f(x)$ and try to choose several upper bounds $g(x)$.  See if you can come up with the (counter)examples you are thinking of.