# Sum of $n+1$ power terms is infinite geometric series plus $O(r^{n+1})$

Tags: real-analysis, proof-verification, asymptotics

I want to show that for $|r|<1$, $$\sum\limits_{k=0}^n r^k =\frac{1}{1-r}+\mathcal{O}(r^{n+1})$$

But I'm not certain if my approach is actually correct. Here is how I show it:

$$\sum\limits_{k=0}^n r^k = \frac{1-r^{n+1}}{1-r}=\frac{1}{1-r}+\frac{r^{n+1}}{r-1}$$
Now, $$\left|\frac{r^{n+1}}{r-1}\right|\le\frac{1}{1-r}\text{sgn}(r^{n+1})r^{n+1}$$

My constant in this case is $\frac{1}{1-r}$, but my function is not exactly $r^{n+1}$, which, however, I don't think actually matters. Please let me know what you think.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, let us clarify what big-oh notation means: we'll say $f(x)=O(g(x))$ if $|f(x)|\leq C\cdot |g(x)|$ for some fixed $C>0$. To extend it to "equality" we have: $f(x)=g(x)+O(h(x))$ if $|f(x)-g(x)|\leq C\cdot |h(x)|$ for some fixed $C>0$.

Now, assuming $r$ is **not** fixed, what you're trying to prove is false unless you know $|r|\leq 1-\varepsilon$ for some given $\varepsilon>0$ (really, you only need $r\in[-1,1-\varepsilon]$ ). The reason is that, as you have already shown, you have $$\sum_{k=0}^n r^k=\frac{1}{1-r}+\frac{r^{n+1}}{r-1}.$$ That is, $$\left|\frac{1}{1-r}-\sum_{k=0}^n r^k\right|\leq\frac{r^{n+1}}{1-r}.$$ There is no way to eliminate the $1-r$ in the denominator, so for any fixed $C>0$, to show that the bound doesn't hold, all we need to do is take $r$ close enough to $1$ (this is why if we know $r\leq1-\varepsilon$, we can provide a constant that depends on $\varepsilon$). However, this *does* show that $$\sum_{k=0}^n r^k = \frac{1}{1-r}+O\left(\frac{r^{n+1}}{1-r}\right).$$

However, if $r$ **is** fixed, then $|1-r|$ is a constant, so the big-oh term above becomes $O(r^{n+1})$ because $|1-r|$ can be absorbed into the constant.

Comment: This is the first time I'm seeing a big-oh definition involving the absolute value on RHS. Even though this does make sense to me, usually there is no absolute value in this definition. This makes sense because if $f(x) = c$ for some negative constant $c$ then $f=O(f)$ only when $c$ is taken in absolute value. Moreover, this definition would work for complex functions as well. But I'm not sure if I can use it nevertheless.

Comment: So what if $r$ is a negative or complex constant, I think your definition will work, but in my book and in many other places the definition does not involve the absolute value on the RHS. This is confusing.

Comment: @sequence: [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation) uses the notation this way; the article states that $g(x)$ is real-valued, but the only way that we can have $|f(x)|\leq Mg(x)$ is if $g(x)\geq0$ for all $x\geq x_0$. Even [MIT](http://web.mit.edu/16.070/www/lecture/big_o.pdf) uses the notation this way, explicitly using absolute values on the RHS; in every context I've ever seen big-O notation, it has been implicit that the function inside $O(\cdot)$ is positive.

Comment: @sequence: If $r$ is negative or complex, the above estimates hold exactly as stated.

Comment: In the definitions I've seen it is assumed that $g(x)$ is positive for all $x\ge x_0$, where $x_0$ is some threshold value. So I think in this case it makes sense to use the absolute value. The only possible issue here, however, is that $g(x)$ and $|g(x)|$ are different functions in general. However, if we assume $\tilde{g}(x) = |g(x)|$ then these definitions should be equivalent.

Answer (score 0):

If you're trying to find $c\in \mathbb{R}_{>0}$ such that

$$\left| \frac{r^{n+1}}{r-1} \right| \le cr^{n+1}$$ for all $n \ge n_0$ for some $n_0$, then you can't for $r < 0$, as the LHS is always at least $0$, while the RHS is less than $0$ infinitely often due to the sign alternation.

Comment: That's why I'm using the sign function in my proof.

Comment: Yes, so you're not using a constant, as the sgn applied to $r^{n+1}$ will alternate.

Comment: Have to sleep now, but in case I wasn't clear in the above, LHS denotes the Left Hand Side of the inequality, and RHS is abbreviated analogously. The main point of the above is that no what what positive constant $c$ you choose, the RHS will be $< 0$ infinitely often, while the LHS is always $\ge 0$, so the inequality above can never hold.

Comment: I see now. Thanks for clarifying. @Metric

Comment: This is not correct; big-oh notation always takes absolute values, so you need not worry about sign changes.

Comment: The post is correct, as I don't see anything "false" within it. Big-oh does not "always" take absolute values; please provide a reference to this claim. The domain of Big-oh is, usually in the references that I use where Big-oh is of huge importance, functions that are asymptotically non-negative.  Therefore in this case, $r^{n+1}$ isn't in the domain of Big-oh for $r < 0$, so $O(r^{n+1})$ is undefined. However, I understood what OP meant, so I addressed that concern instead.

Comment: @Metric: I'm sorry, but this post **is** incorrect. I listed two links below (Wikipedia and MIT). As far as being asymptotically non-negative, I can accept that...but this allows us to extend to the real line via absolute values since all that would remain is a compact set (on which, there will be a maximum since the function is continuous). If we **can** extend it, then why not? Perhaps different branches of mathematics use the big-Oh notation differently, but as far as analytic number theory is concerned, big-Oh *always* takes absolute values.

Comment: See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17128087/big-o-of-a-function-taking-on-a-negative-value), [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2282237/two-different-definitions-of-big-o-relating-to-the-absolute-value), and [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2325086/big-oh-notation-for-complex-functions) just for examples.

Comment: Again, you say my post is "incorrect". Please point out a "false" statement within my post, and I'll happily agree with you. It was clear that OP does not use the definition of Big-oh where absolute values are used (otherwise he/she would not have this problem), so my post simply indicates that, with his/her definition of Big-oh (note the "IF" keyword in my post), it is not possible to prove the statement that concerned him/her. The Wikipedia and MIT articles you referenced do not prove your claim of "big-oh notation "always" takes absolute values". You simply provided examples where they do.

Comment: And please don't get me wrong. I would prefer it that authors use the absolute value signs explicitly in the definition, as it points out the main idea behind Big-oh (asymptotic boundedness), but please understand that not all authors do, which can lead to confusion among some of his readers who are working through a "rigorous" text. Also, apologies for responding so late. I just didn't feel like bickering over the weekend.